# Using a boolean Mask on large numpy array is very slow

Tags: python, performance, numpy, boolean, masking

I have a performance issue when coding with python.
let's say I have 2 very large arrays (Nx2) of strings say with N = 12,000,000, and two variables label_a and label_b which are also strings. Here is the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import time

indices = np.array([np.random.choice(np.arange(5000).astype(str),size=10000000),np.random.choice(np.arange(5000).astype(str),size=10000000)]).T
costs = np.random.uniform(size=10000000)

label_a = '2'
label_b = '9'

t0 = time.time()    

costs = costs[(indices[:,0]!=label_a)*(indices[:,0]!=label_b)*(indices[:,1]!=label_a)*(indices[:,1]!=label_b)]
indices = indices[(indices[:,0]!=label_a)*(indices[:,0]!=label_b)*(indices[:,1]!=label_a)*(indices[:,1]!=label_b)]

t1 = time.time()
toseq = t1-t0
print(toseq)
```

the above code segment takes 3 seconds every time it's ran. I would like to achieve the same thing while reducing the computing cost:
I am using a boolean mask to only retrieve rows in the costs and indices arrays where the values are not label_a and label_b

Comment: Can you please provide some example data for `costs`, `indices`, `indix`, `cost_`, `label_a` and `label_b`? It doesn't have to be to scale (so, not 12 million items), but just a few to give a sense of the type of data and to show that your code actually works. Ideally, just add a few declarations to the start of your code example, so that it works as a whole.

Comment: `idx=np.nonzero(indices...)` and `costs[idx]` may reduce time.

Comment: @Grismar done. thanks I was also thinking about it.

Comment: @hpaulj I believe this has made situation slightly better, the two lines of interest go from 2.6  to 1.6secs on my machine. This is great, I will use that from the time being. still I'd like to perhaps go subseconds and beyond.

Comment: You might also want to time separately the mask/idx creation step, and the actual indexing step.  I don't recall from past testing when indexing times depend on the proportion of taken values or not (though that could easily be tested).  If mask creationg dominates, you may need to focus on making that more efficient.

Comment: @hpaulj Okay, I will update with the time comparison. This problem is crucial because the code is iterated 5000, given one iteration is dominated by these above, the code may have to run between 2 and 4 hours. The algorithm I'm working on competes against more mainstream ones which would run on same data sets in seconds or mere minutes I believe.

Comment: @hpaulj alright so the solution with np.nonzero() doesn't improve on just indexing with the full mask. It avoids computing the mask twice like I am currently doing so this is where the improvement lies. Now the code snippet runs for 1.5secs consistently instead of  2.6 sec. Timed separately idx =  np.nonzero() takes 0.5 secs while costs = costs[idx] and indices = indices[idx] take 0.5 secs each totalling 1.5 secs (I am rounding the numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, computing the values of the indices you're after only once, and combining them only once would save time.

(I've also changed the way of timing, just for brevity - the results are the same)

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

r = 5000
n = 10000000

indices = np.array([
    np.random.choice(np.arange(r).astype(str), size=n),
    np.random.choice(np.arange(r).astype(str), size=n)
]).T
costs = np.random.uniform(size=n)

label_a = '2'
label_b = '9'

n_indices = np.array([
    np.random.choice(np.arange(r), size=n),
    np.random.choice(np.arange(r), size=n)
]).T


def run():
    global indices
    global costs

    _ = costs[(indices[:, 0] != label_a)*(indices[:, 0] != label_b) *
              (indices[:, 1] != label_a)*(indices[:, 1] != label_b)]
    _ = indices[(indices[:, 0] != label_a)*(indices[:, 0] != label_b) *
                (indices[:, 1] != label_a)*(indices[:, 1] != label_b)]


def run_faster():
    global indices
    global costs

    # only compute these only once
    not_a0 = indices[:, 0] != label_a
    not_b0 = indices[:, 0] != label_b
    not_a1 = indices[:, 1] != label_a
    not_b1 = indices[:, 1] != label_b
    _ = costs[not_a0 * not_b0 * not_a1 * not_b1]
    _ = indices[not_a0 * not_b0 * not_a1 * not_b1]


def run_even_faster():
    global indices
    global costs

    # also combine them only once
    cond = ((indices[:, 0] != label_a) * (indices[:, 0] != label_b) *
            (indices[:, 1] != label_a) * (indices[:, 1] != label_b))
    _ = costs[cond]
    _ = indices[cond]


def run_sep_mask():
    global indices
    global costs
    global cond

    # just the masking part of run_even_faster
    cond = ((indices[:, 0] != label_a) * (indices[:, 0] != label_b) *
            (indices[:, 1] != label_a) * (indices[:, 1] != label_b))


def run_sep_index():
    global indices
    global costs
    global cond

    # just the indexing part of run_even_faster
    _ = costs[cond]
    _ = indices[cond]


def run_even_faster_numerical():
    global indices
    global costs

    # use int values and n_indices instead of indices
    a = int(label_a)
    b = int(label_b)

    cond = ((n_indices[:, 0] != a) * (n_indices[:, 0] != b) *
            (n_indices[:, 1] != a) * (n_indices[:, 1] != b))
    _ = costs[cond]
    _ = indices[cond]


def run_all(funcs):
    for f in funcs:
        print('{:.4f} : {}()'.format(timeit(f, number=1), f.__name__))


run_all([run, run_faster, run_even_faster, run_sep_mask, run_sep_index, run_even_faster_numerical])
```

Note that I also added an example where the operation is not based on strings, but on numbers instead. If you can avoid the values being strings, but get numbers instead, you'd get a performance boost as well.

This boost gets substantial if you start comparing longer labels - in the end it might even be worth converting the strings to numbers before the filtering, if the strings get long enough.

These are my results:

```
0.9711 : run()
0.7065 : run_faster()
0.6983 : run_even_faster()
0.2657 : run_sep_mask()
0.4174 : run_sep_index()
0.4536 : run_even_faster_numerical()
```

The two `sep` entries show that the indexing is about twice the amount of time it takes to build the mask for `run_even_faster`, so you can only expect so much improvement from tuning it even more.

However, they also show that building the mask based on integers is less than 0.04 seconds on top of doing the actual indexing, compared to the about 0.26 seconds for building the mask based on strings. So, that's the room you have for improvement.

Comment: Also note that I don't like using globals, but I wanted to stay close to the original code - don't use globals if you don't have to.

Comment: Alright I have made edits to the code and implemented a version of run_even_faster_numerical(). Thanks a lot for your assistance! Right now I'm down to 0.4 per iteration which would take a little more than 30 mins to compute. The algorithm is perhaps now usable on large data sets. Not sure if there are other ways to squeeze performance out of this but unsure until I enlist an engineer on this 

Comment: I think that, if you're getting close to the value of `run_sep_index()` on your machine, there's not a whole lot you can do, since that's just the speed of indexing in `numpy`. You might consider combining the two (costs and indices) so your script only has to index once - that might be a good trade off for having to traverse the slightly bigger data set when building the mask.